# Replacing variables into a multiline shell variable

Tags: php, sql, shell, variables, multiline

I'm building an email message by reading some rows from a database into a multiple line shell variable called EMAIL_DESC:

```
EMAIL_DESC=`run "select text from  ETL.MAIL_TEXT where ID=1 order by id, text_order"`
```

Unfortunately I have variables and commands (`date`) inside $EMAIL_DESC but I can't substitute them in any way.

```
echo "$EMAIL_DESC"
Please be aware that all user tables and views on the $SERVER_DESC
Ended = `date`.
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question is not very clear. But whatever I can understand I think you're looking for the evil eval here. Consider this:

```
x='Foo
Bar
$HOME
Baz
$SHELL'

echo $x
eval echo $x
```

#### OUTPUT:

```
Foo Bar $HOME Baz $SHELL
Foo Bar /home/alex Baz /bin/bash
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

At the end of every line in the database I have to add "\\n" (newline) and I have to change eval to accept extra parameters from echo (-e):

```
eval "echo -e "${EMAIL_DESC}" "
```

Thanks again
Alex